# cannot import dynamically generated sqlalchemy classes in flask-python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Just started learning flask and python and I had to create 10+ tables(MySQLAlchemy) with the same structure and constraints. so after looking aroud for a quicker solution than declaring each class separately, I did the following in models/user.py:

```
#models/users.py
class exchangeapis(object):

email = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
api =db.Column(db.String(100))
secret= db.Column(db.String(100))



@declared_attr.cascading 

# Makes sure all the dbs derived from this calss get the fK and PK

def email(cls):
        #this is necessary to propagate fk and pk to the instances
        return db.Column(db.String(50), db.ForeignKey('users.email'), primary_key=True)

#general methods to get class data       
def get_api(self):
    return self.api

def get_secret(self):
    return self.secret

exchange=['A','B','C']    
for exchange in exchanges:

cls=type(exchange.title(), (exchangeapis, db.Model), { '__tablename__' : str(exchange)+"_api"})
print(cls.__name__)
```

the

```
print(cls.__name__)
```

gives me 'A', 'B', 'C' which I expect to be 'A_api', 'B_api'...

when I try to import it into my account/views.py file,  with the following:

```
from ..models import User, A_api
```

I get "  File "/home/puru991/flask-saas/flask-base/app/account/views.py", line 8, in 
    from ..models import User,A_api

ImportError: cannot import name 'A_api'"

but if i define the class in the following way:

```
class A_api(db.Model):
__tablename__="A_api"
email = db.Column(db.String(50),ForeignKey("users.email"), primary_key=True)
api =db.Column(db.String(100))
secret= db.Column(db.String(100))

#general methods to get class data       
def get_api(self):
    return self.api

def get_secret(self):
    return self.secret
```

There are no errors. So my questions is how do I dynamically create classes based on exchangeapi(object) and import them successfully?
I went through about 8-10 answers around here and the most i could learn was how to create them dynamically.  I also learnt that MySQLAlchemy creates classes with the same name as the tablename, so I thought referring by the table name(which is "A_api") would do the trick. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you cannot import them is because in your `users.py` file you do not have a variable called `A_api`.

```
exchange=['A','B','C']    
for exchange in exchanges:
    cls=type(exchange.title(), (exchangeapis, db.Model), { '__tablename__' : str(exchange)+"_api"})
    print(cls.__name__)
```

In the code above you are creating three classes and each time you assign the class to a variable called `cls`. Once the for loop has finished your variable `cls` will be the last class created and technically you could import this variable into another module (don't do this though).

You can see this if you run the following code:

```
exchange=['A','B','C']    
for exchange in exchanges:
    cls=type(exchange.title(), (exchangeapis, db.Model), { '__tablename__' : str(exchange)+"_api"})

# This will print C_api as it's the last assignment to cls in the for loop
print(cls.__name__)
```

Regarding the table names/class names; you've got it the wrong way around, Flask-SQLAlchemy [derives the table name](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/#declaring-models) from the class name, converting a class called “CamelCase” to a table called “camel_case”, unless you override the table name using `__tablename__`. Allowing the table name to be defined allows you to use a more Pythonic named class name but use a more conventional DB table name.

See a simple demonstration below of working code, two files `models.py` and `run.py`:

**models.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

# This list will hold the dynamically created classes
dynamic_models = []

db = SQLAlchemy()


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    email = db.Column(db.String(254), primary_key=True)
    # Other User fields


class ExchangeApiMixin(object):

    @declared_attr.cascading
    def email(cls):
        return db.Column(db.String(254), db.ForeignKey('users.email'), primary_key=True)

    api = db.Column(db.String(100))

    secret = db.Column(db.String(100))


for exchange in ['A_api', 'B_api', 'C_api']:
    cls = type(exchange, (ExchangeApiMixin, db.Model), {})
    print(cls.__name__)
    dynamic_models.append(cls)

# This will print C_api as it's the last assignment to cls in the for loop
print(cls.__name__)


# Individual variables also reference the dynamically created classes. The could be any legal python variable name
A_API = dynamic_models[0]
B_API = dynamic_models[1]
C_API = dynamic_models[2]

# Succinct way of creating the dynamic classes
(D_API, E_API, F_API) = [type(exchange, (ExchangeApiMixin, db.Model), {}) for exchange in ['D_api', 'E_api', 'F_api']]
```

**run.py**

```
import random, string
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from models import db, dynamic_models, A_API, B_API, C_API, cls, D_API

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
db.init_app(app)


_template = '''
    {% for rows in queries %}
        <table border='1'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>API</th>
            <th>Secret</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>    
            {% for row in rows %}
                <tr>
                <td>{{row.__class__.__name__}}</td>
                <td>{{row.email}}</td>
                <td>{{row.api}}</td>
                <td>{{row.secret}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <p></p>
    {% endfor %}        
'''


@app.route('/')
def index():
    # display all the A_API, B_API, C_API, D_API instances
    a_rows = A_API.query.all()
    b_rows = B_API.query.all()
    c_rows = C_API.query.all()
    d_rows = D_API.query.all()
    return render_template_string(_template, queries=[a_rows, b_rows, c_rows, d_rows])


def build_sample_db():
    with app.app_context():

        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()

        def create_from_model(Model, api_name):
            for _ in range(0, 10):
                _model = Model(
                    email='{mailbox}@example.com'.format(mailbox=''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=10))),
                    api=api_name,
                    secret='pa$$w0rd'
                )
                db.session.add(_model)

            db.session.commit()

        # Create instances using A_API, could pass dynamic_models[0]
        create_from_model(Model=A_API, api_name='A API Name')

        # Create using B_API instances
        create_from_model(Model=dynamic_models[1], api_name='B API Name')

        # Create using C_API instances using the cls variable (which is the 'C' class
        create_from_model(Model=cls, api_name='C API Name')

        # Create using D_API instances
        create_from_model(Model=D_API, api_name='D API Name')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_sample_db()
    app.run()
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks and noted. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks!! Just what I needed!